# Watermark with sharp

Tags: node.js, sharp

I have a image and i put watermark there, but i want that watermark hs a opacity like 30%.

My code:

```
    let sharp = require('sharp');
    let buffer = null;

    await sharp(image)
        .composite([{ input: './logo.png', gravity: 'center' }])
        .sharpen()
        .withMetadata()
        .toBuffer()
        .then(function(outputBuffer) {
            buffer = outputBuffer;
        });
    return buffer;
```

How can i say that logo has opacity like 30%?

Comment: I believe you would need to composite another image which just has an alpha channel at 0.7, and use blend mode "dest-in"

Comment: @Asthmatic Sorry i didnt understod.
can you pass a example code?

Comment: something like https://github.com/lovell/sharp/issues/405#issuecomment-208033263 but set the blend mode to `dest-in`... but in your case you don't need a reducer because it would just be 2 images

Comment: @Asthmatic I do that and all image be black, and watermark was 0% of opacity

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Sharp cant do this yet.

Alternative method is use canvas to change image opacity before composite.
https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/blob/master/examples/globalAlpha.js

Answer (score 0):

Your need to change the opacity of "logo.png" use `blur`, then compose it like code snipp above.